# SQLite: How to insert the same value to multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I want to provide the same value which is a TimeStamp to all the columns in the table. Let's say the columns are unknown.
Is there any way to do this like
 `INSERT INTO table VALUES ('one value');` 
without specifying the column names?

**UPDATE:**

Let's say i have a table named 'student' and i have 'f_name', 'm_name', and 'l_name' in it.

Let's say (Hypothetically) i do `INSERT INTO student VALUES ('John');`

Then i want my table to look like this.

```
-----------student------------
 f_name  |   m_name  |  l_name
------------------------------
  John   |    John   |   John    <--- (The record i just inserted)
```

Comment: It is possible to do an `UPDATE` on all records.  You can simply omit any `WHERE` restriction.  But for `INSERT` it doesn't make sense, because how will the RDBMS even know to stop (or start) inserting the desired number of records?

Comment: It's not about rows. It's one record anyways. I don't know how to explain this further. Sorry. It's actually really simple what i'm asking for. Just one value to all columns.

Comment: Do you know the number of columns or is this also unknown?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please check the update. This is as much as i can explain. To answer your question, yes. The number of columns are also unknown.

Comment: The only way I can see to do this would be to first query the columns from your table.  But it is good practice to force you to list the columns.  What would happen if, for example, one column were type `TINYINT`?  Your insert could cause an error.  In general, you should not be doing a blind insert of data across an entire record.

Comment: Actually i have that solution programmatical wise. I'm querying 'PRAGMA table_info()' and taking the count to generate a String like 'datetime('now'), datetime('now'), datetime('now')' using a loop. But it would be so much better if i could solve this from the DB side.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in postgres actually. I dont think you can do it in sqlite. With the following query you can generate the insert statement that you want without having to know the columns of the table. Replace MY_TABLE with the table name you have in your DB.

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE ' || array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT '' || c.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns As c
            WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE' 
    ), ',') || ' VALUES (' ||
array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT '' || '\'MY_VALUE\''
        FROM information_schema.columns As c
            WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE' 
    ), ',') || ');' 
    As sqlstmt
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need but in SQLite. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite and Mysql does not support multi-table insertion on a single query.

Sqlite
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

MySql
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

However there are some other databases that support such features i.e Oracle. As far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the numbers of columns then you can use

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('Cardinal',..........,'Cardinal');  //As many times as number of columns
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  You need column names here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen According to w3school.com The first form does not specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

`INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);`

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).  The page you saw was most likely for generic SQL, not specifically the MySQL dialect.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = 'Value';
```

This will only work if you already have data in your Table.

Comment: Yep. What i need is a new record.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column names, you can do this:

```sql
insert into student (f_name, m_name, l_name)
select a, a, a from (select 'John' as a ) x
```

Works on mysql and probably most other databases

Comment: Did you miss *without specifying the column names* in the question?